# Boschloo's exact test

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, contingency-tables, association-measure, exact-test

I have following data in R:

```
 d1 <- matrix(c(24,2,63,11),2,2,
                dimnames=list(X=c("present", "absent"),Y=c("present", "absent")))
```

I want to test whether X and Y are independent or not. In the above 2X2 contingency table, there is a cell whose expected count is less than 5. Hence I am performing exact test. Also no margins are fixed here. So I am doing Boschloo's exact test with a multinomial model. This test can be computed in the ["Exact" package in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Exact/Exact.pdf), using [?exact.test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Exact/versions/1.0/topics/exact.test).  But I have difficulty to understand the arguments inside it. As far I understand, I need only 4 arguments in my situation:

```
exact.test(d1, alternative="two.sided", method="boschloo", model="Multinomial")
```

But the `exact.test` have some other arguments, such as, `npNumbers` which is the number of nuisance parameters considered. It seems the default value of `npNumbers` is 100. But I am not understanding how is the number of nuisance parameters 100 for a 2X2 contingency table?

Comment: The question **"I am not understanding how is the number of nuisance parameters 100 for a 2X2 contingency table?"**  seems more about statistical issue rather than only R codes.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what the answer is and so this is only a comment but there are some hints in the manual. The function returns the value of the nuisance parameter(s). If you increase npNumbers the routine takes longer. My hypothesis is therefore that this is the fineness of the grid of values over which it searches for the nuisance parameter. You could always e-mail the maintainer.

Comment: Although asked in terms of an R function. I think this is actually a statistical question (as in, "needs statistical expertise to answer"). I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @mdewey: Quite right: there are only two nuisance parameters under a multinomial sampling scheme & this function argument specifies how many values to check (before running an optimization routine around the values for which it finds the maximum p-value).

Comment: The pdf https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Exact/Exact.pdf  defines `npNumbers` as "the number of nuisance parameters considered". But in the link https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Exact/versions/1.0/topics/exact.test (gung gave the link while he edited the post) `npNumbers` is defined as "Increment for the search in the nuisance parameter". Sounds @mdewey 's hypothesis is correct.